# scientific notation abstraction in java

Tags: java, math, scientific-notation

Is there a java class abstraction to denote scientific numbers `(e.g. the number, 10 power modulus)`, so that I can do simple operations like multiplication or division on top of them.

Note: Looking for something similar to [Fraction](http://commons.apache.org/math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math/fraction/Fraction.html) here.

Comment: I thought those were called "double".  What additional abstraction do you think you need?  I can certainly write this: double modulus = 3.0e7;  What else did you have in mind?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Emil said, BigDecimal helps you.  It doesn't have a constructor that lets you enter a double mantissa and an int exponent.  You could extend the class to make a new constructor, or, you could define a DecimalFormat.  I think that the class DecimalFormat will do some of what you want.  It allows you how to define how a number 'looks'.  You need to define the format using a String, the tutorial is 
http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html

You would have to define the format of scientific numbers, call `yourDecimalFormat.parse(yourStringtoBecomeScientificNumber)` which will give you a Number, then cast it as a BigDecimal to do arithmetic on it.

Also note that this should allow you to force a certain number of significant figures or digits to left of decimal point.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't get your example.If you need a different type of number representation then you can do so by extending abstract class [Number](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html).Also have a look at [BigDecimals](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) .I think this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You could write the number as number+e+exponent, e.g.:
1e2 instead of 100. 
Multiplication and Division should work for it.

Comment: Note that you are limited to the range `1e-308` to `1e308`.

Comment: Didn't get what the type would be, if I have to represent this as 1e2.